# Does TensorFlow have cross validation implemented?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I was thinking of trying to choose hyper parameters (like regularization for example) using cross validation or maybe train multiple initializations of a models and then choose the model with highest cross validation accuracy. Implementing k-fold or CV is simple but tedious/annoying (specially if I am trying to train different models in different CPU's, GPU's or even different computers etc). I would expect a library like TensorFlow to have something like this implemented for its user so that we don't have to code the same thing 100 times. Thus, does TensorFlow have a library or something that can help me do Cross Validation?

---

As an update, it seems one could use scikit learn or something else to do this. If this is the case, then if anyone can provide a simple example of NN training and cross validation with scikit learn it would be awesome! Not sure if this scales to multiple cpus, gpus, clusters etc though.

Comment: TF is just a computational library, not a ML library as such. What is wrong with simply using scikit-learn around it? You have too much data to load it to memory and you need "op"-based data splitting?

Comment: I wasn't aware you could use scikit-learn for this. Nice! I will check it out. (I wonder if it scales for lots of computers and stuff like that)

Answer (score 22):

As already discussed, tensorflow doesn't provide its own way to cross-validate the model. The recommended way is to use [`KFold`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html). It's a bit tedious, but doable. Here's a complete example of cross-validating MNIST model with `tensorflow` and `KFold`:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 500

# TF graph
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("data/mnist-tf", one_hot=True)
train_x_all = mnist.train.images
train_y_all = mnist.train.labels
test_x = mnist.test.images
test_y = mnist.test.labels

def run_train(session, train_x, train_y):
  print "\nStart training"
  session.run(init)
  for epoch in range(10):
    total_batch = int(train_x.shape[0] / batch_size)
    for i in range(total_batch):
      batch_x = train_x[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
      batch_y = train_y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
      _, c = session.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
      if i % 50 == 0:
        print "Epoch #%d step=%d cost=%f" % (epoch, i, c)

def cross_validate(session, split_size=5):
  results = []
  kf = KFold(n_splits=split_size)
  for train_idx, val_idx in kf.split(train_x_all, train_y_all):
    train_x = train_x_all[train_idx]
    train_y = train_y_all[train_idx]
    val_x = train_x_all[val_idx]
    val_y = train_y_all[val_idx]
    run_train(session, train_x, train_y)
    results.append(session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: val_x, y: val_y}))
  return results

with tf.Session() as session:
  result = cross_validate(session)
  print "Cross-validation result: %s" % result
  print "Test accuracy: %f" % session.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_x, y: test_y})
```

Comment: Shouldn't you start Session() and reset the graph for each fold ?

Comment: @Maxim, why you use epochs with 10 fold? I think if you use 10 fold, it does not need to loop over epochs, it's in itself 10 epoch?

Comment: @HunarA.Ahmed You still want to train each model to convergence inside each fold. So doing cross validation in no way removes the need for multiple epochs.

Answer (score 1):

As the dataset gets larger cross validation gets more expensive. In deep learning we usually use large data sets.You should be fine with simple training. Tensorflow doesnt have a built in mechanism for cv as it is not usually used in neural networks. In neural networks, the efficiency of the network relies mainly on the data set, number of epochs and the learning rate.

I have used cv in sklearn
You can check the link:
https://github.com/hackmaster0110/Udacity-Data-Analyst-Nano-Degree-Projects/

In that,go to poi_id.py in Identify fraud from enron data(In Project folder)

Comment: This is simply not true.

Comment: @SteveSeverance could you elaborate on why this answer is incorrect?